# Can a low cost IMU compensate for wheel slip induced heading errors?

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a two wheeled differential drive robot with a Kinect, similar in shape and form to a TurtleBot. The odometry data provides for beautiful straight lines, but when turning there is a tremendous amount of wheel slip on some surfaces, but little or none on others, making it impossible to predict. The result is very strangely shaped rooms.

I have already experimented with compasses (magnetometers?) and am aware that indoor environments are a sea of magnetic distortion of every kind. So I do not think a "compass" can help.

My limited understanding is that an IMU (AHRS?) can help correct the heading error, but I am concerned that they may  not be able to deal with the normal magnetic disturbances inside of a building. I cannot tell from online research if such IMUs are able to compensate for variable magnetic disturbances, such as are found in a building, or if they will be just as poor at estimating a heading as a digital "compass".

I've found two low cost IMUs:
CH Robotic's UM 7:
[www.chrobotics.com/shop/um7-lt-orientation-sensor](http://www.chrobotics.com/shop/um7-lt-orientation-sensor)
The 9DOF Razor IMU:
[www.sparkfun.com/products/10736](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736)

Will either of these provide an accurate enough heading estimate to correct error caused by wheel slip during rotation in an indoor environment?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175226/can-a-low-cost-imu-compensate-for-wheel-slip-induced-heading-errors?/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Measuring the angular rate around the z-axis is performed using a single gydro on the Turtlebot, see [Calibrate Odometry and Gyro](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro). Replicating that setup seems like a straightforward approach. You can of course also use a 6 or 9 DOF IMU for the task and just use the z-axis gyro data, ignoring the other axes.
Note that you´ll be able to reduce error due to slip, but noise in sensor data will always results in some odometry drift, so you´ll probably want to use AMCL or gmapping to get proper localization and/or mapping.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on 2014-06-29**:
That connected the dots for me. I can get a simple gyro much cheaper and experiment with it using the Turtlebot as an example. It seems obvious now, but I needed a pointer. Thank you.